# Can't open file error in Perl

Tags: perl, file

**Why program can't open the file? i.e dies.** I searched for this problem, but it seems all fine to me.
Funny thing is this code worked before, and i don't think i changed something from that moment in open function.

```
my $i;
my $regex = $ARGV[0];

for (@ARGV[1 .. $#ARGV]){
    open (my $fh, "<", "$_") or die ("Can't open, $!");
    $i++;
    foreach (<$fh>){
        print "Given regexp: $regex\nfile$i:\n   line $.: $1\n" if $_ =~ /(\b$regex\b)/;
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**
Can't open **Not a directory**

Comment: check what file is your script opening, since it doesn't exist `.. or die "[$_] $!";`

Comment: Try changing the `or die` to be `or die ("Can't open {$_}, $!")`. Note the curly braces around `$_` so you see exactly what was being opened.

Comment: @mpapec,thx again, silly mistake i have inputed a wrong argument as ARGV.

Answer (score 2):

**Not a directory** means you're supplying an argument that assumes a non-directory is a directory.

For instance, if your argument is

```
a/b
```

and

```
a
```

exists but is not a directory, you will get this error.

Answer (score 1):

Check your argument. it should be a proper directory name